# Snapshot isolation for reliable queue is broken?

Tags: c#, concurrency, transactions, azure-service-fabric

**UPDATE:** This bug was fixed in [Service Fabric SDK version 2.4.164](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/02/03/release-of-sdk-2-4-164-and-runtime-5-4-164-for-windows/) on February 3, 2017. Quote from [release notes](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/02/Microsoft-Azure-Service-Fabric-Release-Notes-SDK-2.4.164-Runtime-5.4.164.docx):

> **Fix to ReliableQueue to correctly handle additional transaction levels and combinations**
>
> Fixing a bug where ReliableQueue.GetCountAsync did not adhere to Snapshot Isolation if it was also doing Read Your Own Write. This issue was originally reported on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529193/snapshot-isolation-for-reliable-queue-is-broken). Thank you for your bug reports.

---

I'm in the process of writing mocks for Service Fabric reliable collections. I need these mocks to mimic the transactional behavior of the real implementation as close as possible.

I have therefore written a couple of test cases that I run to verify that my mocks behave like the real implementation.

However, in some test cases dealing with snapshot isolation I discovered that my mocks have a different behavior. But after looking closer I'm not so sure that the fault is on my side.

So I think that I may have stumbled on a bug in how reliable queue enforce snapshot isolation.

The [MSDN docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections/) for snapshot isolation says:

> The transaction can recognize only data modifications that were committed before the start of the transaction. Data modifications made by other transactions after the start of the current transaction are not visible to statements executing in the current transaction.

And:

> Reliable Queue support Read Your Writes. In other words, any write within a transaction will be visible to a following read that belongs to the same transaction.

So, an operation that mandate snapshot isolation, like `GetCountAsync`, should see a consistent snapshot that is unaffected by other transactions. Only changes made by the transaction that owns the snapshot shall be visible.

This is indeed the case for reliable dictionaries, but not for reliable queues.

Snapshots taken for a reliable queue (by doing `GetCountAsync` or `CreateEnumerableAsync`) are indeed unaffected by modifications made by other transactions but only if we don't make any changes ourselves. Doing so will not only make our own changes visible in the snapshot but also expose changes from other transactions.

The following snippet can be dropped into a reliable service to reproduce this:

```
public async Task Verify_that_reliable_queue_snapshot_isolation_is_broken()
{
    // Get an empty reliable queue
    var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var queue = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<string>>(name);

    // Start transaction and take a snapshot by getting queue count
    var t1 = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, await queue.GetCountAsync(t1)); // ok

    // Enqueue something in a concurrent transaction
    using (var t2 = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        await queue.EnqueueAsync(t2, "something");
        await t2.CommitAsync();
    }

    // Snapshot should still say zero
    Assert.AreEqual(0, await queue.GetCountAsync(t1)); // ok

    // Enqueue something else in the first transaction
    await queue.EnqueueAsync(t1, "something else");

    // Count should now be 1 in t1, but it's actually 2.
    Assert.AreEqual(2 /* should be 1*/, await queue.GetCountAsync(t1)); // broken!
}
```

I need to know whether this is by design, and the documentation is incorrect, or whether this is a bug. Or if I have misunderstood something.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue Marten. This is a bug in Reliable Queue. We will fix it as soon as possible. I apologize for any inconvenience.

I will update on this thread when the issue is fixed.